# SwiftUI: How to pass scrollTransition's phase value to my @State property

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

```
.scrollTransition { view, phase in
    view.opacity(phase.isIdentity ? 1 : 0)
        .scaleEffect(phase.isIdentity ? 1 : 0.75)
 }
```

Is there anyway to pass the **phase.isIdentity** to my **@State** bool property?

iOS 17

Comment: This is probably an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Can you give more context? ***Why*** do you want this to be a `@State`? What are you planning on using this `@State` for?

Comment: You could use a PreferenceKey. For example: https://gist.github.com/talhanai/3d1e03ae2a645b97867ff32abb473aad

Comment: @Sweeper On my visionOS app, I hope I can pass scrollTransition's [ phase.isIdentiy ] value to my State bool property, then I can use this State bool property to drive my RealityView state change.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what `phase.isIdentiy` is. There is no "single" `phase` for the whole scroll view. The scroll transition is applied to *all* the views in the scroll view, and each view has its own `phase`, depending on where in the scroll view it is. What "state change" specifically are you trying to drive?

Comment: @Sweeper thank you for your explanation, I did actually misunderstand that, and there is a way to get the position of the scrollview, it's the method called .scrollPosition(id: , anchor: )